# Generation of an image of the Ubuntu running from the SD card

Tags: image, ubuntu, xilinx, zynq

I have a ZYNQ running ubuntu on one of the processors (and baremetal code running on the other one). Everything is currently (and temporarily) running from the SD card, so that it has two partitions, one called BOOT (containing the files BOOT.BIN, image.ub and system.dtb), and another one with the rootfs tree. I have been working with it for a while and I have installed several packages and developed some applications.

My intention now is to use [SWUpdate](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/swupdate.html) to update all the software everytime a new version is released, so that I should generate an image of each of the two partitions. I have seen some tutorials from Xilinx to make a boot image, but I have not seen how to make it from a complete and modified system as the one I've described above. Any help will be greatly welcome.

Comment: You can possibily have a look at the scripts in https://github.com/pokitoz/xilinx_config_zynq/tree/master/linux to see how the uboot, linux, dtb and SD card are build/created